# How to format my json data for stack column chart in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

Here is my json data

```
var data = [
    {"unit":"a", "status":"Stopped / Idle", "val":21.2022222222222222},
    {"unit":"a", "status":"Working", "val":53.3066666666666667},
    {"unit":"a", "status":"Headland Turning", "val":0.04694444444444444444},
    {"unit":"a", "status":"Transport", "val":5.1425000000000000},
    {"unit":"b", "status":"Stopped / Idle", "val":334.7358333333333333},
    {"unit":"b", "status":"Working", "val":212.6386111111111111},
    {"unit":"b", "status":"Headland Turning", "val":26.2955555555555556},
    {"unit":"b", "status":"Transport", "val":0.00444444444444444444}
];
```

`unit` is the category

I want the data could be formatted in the following way so that I can plug in to `series` option in HighCharts:

```
series: [{
                name: 'Stopped / Idle',
                data: [21.2022222222222222, 334.7358333333333333]},
            {
                name: 'Working',
                data: [53.3066666666666667, 212.6386111111111111]},
            {
                name: 'Headland Turning',
                data: [0.04694444444444444444, 26.2955555555555556]},
            {
                name: 'Transport',
                data: [5.1425000000000000, 0.00444444444444444444]}]
        });
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var data = [
    {"unit":"a", "status":"Stopped / Idle", "val":21.2022222222222222},
    {"unit":"a", "status":"Working", "val":53.3066666666666667},
    {"unit":"a", "status":"Headland Turning", "val":0.04694444444444444444},
    {"unit":"a", "status":"Transport", "val":5.1425000000000000},
    {"unit":"b", "status":"Stopped / Idle", "val":334.7358333333333333},
    {"unit":"b", "status":"Working", "val":212.6386111111111111},
    {"unit":"b", "status":"Headland Turning", "val":26.2955555555555556},
    {"unit":"b", "status":"Transport", "val":0.00444444444444444444}
];
var seriesData = [];
var xCategories = [];
var i, cat;
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
     cat = 'Unit ' + data[i].unit;
     if(xCategories.indexOf(cat) === -1){
        xCategories[xCategories.length] = cat;
     }
}
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    if(seriesData){
      var currSeries = seriesData.filter(function(seriesObject){ return seriesObject.name == data[i].status;});
      if(currSeries.length === 0){
          currSeries = seriesData[seriesData.length] = {name: data[i].status, data: []};
      } else {
          currSeries = currSeries[0];
      }
      var index = currSeries.data.length;
      currSeries.data[index] = data[i].val;
    } else {
       seriesData[0] = {name: data[i].status, data: [data[i].val]}
    }
}
```

Now that you've `seriesData` and `xCategories` you can instantiate the chart by using something similar to

```
  chart = new Highchart({chart: {renderTo: 'chart-div', 
                                   type: 'column'
                                  }, 
                           plotOptions: {column: {stacking: 'normal'}},
                           xAxis:{ categories: xCategories}, 
                           series: seriesData
                         });
```

EDIT: Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sujay/UMeGS/

Comment: Thanks I think yours probably would be right. But it's not working in my place, would you please post a working piece in fiddle? Thank you

Comment: @SongtaoZ I've added the jsfiddle as requested, & also fixed certain errors here. Sorry for the initial confusion. I was in a hurry when writing that answer.

Comment: thanks. That's what I am end up going for. I must learn a lot from you code!

Comment: Since Highcharts 3.0, categories can also be extracted by giving each point a name and setting axis type to "category".

Answer (score 1):

On the HighCharts website I navigated to the Demo Gallery > HighChart demos section and clicked on Stacked column on the left side of the page. From there they had a link to a [JSFiddle with a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked/) and from there I saw two sections of code that are pertinent to you.

The first section is the `xAxis` property of the HighChart object. Here's what I changed it to:

```
xAxis: {
  categories: ['Unit A', 'Unit B']
}
```

Those are going to be each of the columns that you are stacking the data upon.

The next section is the `series` property. This is where you pass in the data that you are looking to graph into those columns. It looks like this:

```
series: [{
  name: 'Stopped / Idle',
  data: [21.2022222222222222, 334.7358333333333333]
}, {
  name: 'Working',
  data: [53.3066666666666667, 212.6386111111111111]
}, {
  name: 'Headland Turning',
  data: [0.04694444444444444444, 26.2955555555555556]
}, {
  name: 'Transport',
  data: [5.1425000000000000, 0.00444444444444444444]                         
}]
```

In this portion you specify the name of the particular type of data and then the values for each column you specified in the `xAxis` property.

I played around with some of the options really quick and there is so much more that you can do with this, but [here's the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonmerino/H27rE/2/) with a stacked column graph and your data.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's a bit hard code in it..Actually I want some formatting with my data to plugin the highcharts options

Comment: Hey @Songtao Z, I think I'm not quite understanding the problem. Your data was used in the example I made (I had to rearrange it a bit), there are just a few extra options in the Fiddle. I left them there so you could see more possibilities.

Comment: Sorry jason, thank you for your answer. I've updated my question in case of confusion. I actually know how to which part of HighCharts options it needs to put in my data, just don't know how play around with my JSON data so that can be identified by chart options without any hard coding, which means I don't need to manually put any data in the options. Actually what @Sujay did was what I want, but his code is not working. I've been playing with his code for a while yesterday and still could not figure out how to plugin my json data.