# HighCharts setting categories and series using JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, json, highcharts

I'm trying to get my High chart to work from data that I get from Ajax (JSON) but i think i must be missing something.  I've tried looping through and putting what i need into arrays so that i can put the variable into the xaxis categories and add the results in the series but when i run it I'm getting a script error:

```
A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.

Script: http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js:51
```

Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $("#GetReport").click(function () {

                var manufacturerId = 241;
                var countryId = 230;
                var startDate = '2013-01-09';
                var endDate = '2013-01-30';

                var theUrl = "/ProductStats/Parameters/" + manufacturerId + "/" + countryId + "/" + startDate + "/" + endDate;

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: theUrl,
                    data: { 'manufacturerId': manufacturerId, 'countryId': countryId, 'startDate': startDate, 'endDate': endDate },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {


                        //see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472947/how-to-format-my-json-data-for-stack-column-chart-in-highcharts


                        var WidgetNameArray = [];

                        var impressionsArray = [];

                        var intsArray = [];

                        alert(data.length);

                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                            var item1 = data[i];

                            var widgetCategories = item1.WidgetName;

                            //put into an array
                            WidgetNameArray.push(widgetCategories);

                            var imps = item1.Impressions;

                            impressionsArray.push(imps);

                            var ints = item1.Interactions;

                            intsArray.push(ints);

                        }



                        // Create the chart
                        $('#container').highcharts({
                            chart: {
                                type: 'column'
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: 'Inter Chart ' + startDate + ' to ' + endDate
                            },
                            xAxis: {
                                categories: [WidgetNameArray]
                            },
                            yAxis: {
                                min: 0,
                                title: {
                                    text: 'Impressions/Interactions'
                                },
                                stackLabels: {
                                    enabled: true,
                                    style: {
                                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            legend: {
                                align: 'right',
                                x: -100,
                                verticalAlign: 'top',
                                y: 20,
                                floating: true,
                                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColorSolid) || 'white',
                                borderColor: '#CCC',
                                borderWidth: 1,
                                shadow: false
                            },
                            tooltip: {
                                formatter: function () {
                                    return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                        this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                        'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
                                }
                            },
                            plotOptions: {
                                column: {
                                    stacking: 'normal',
                                    dataLabels: {
                                        enabled: true,
                                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            series: [{
                                name: 'Impressions',
                                data: [impressionsArray]
                            }, {
                                name: 'Interactions',
                                data: [intsArray]
                            }]
                        });




                        var table = document.getElementById("usertable");
                        var tabledata = "";

                        tabledata += "<tr>";
                        tabledata += "<th>Widget Name</th>";
                        tabledata += "<th>Impressions</th>";
                        tabledata += "<th>Interactions</th>";
                        tabledata += "<th>CTR</th>";
                        tabledata += "</tr>";



                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                            var item = data[i];

                            tabledata += "<tr>";
                            tabledata += "<td>" + item.WidgetName + "</td>";
                            tabledata += "<td>" + item.Impressions + "</td>";
                            tabledata += "<td>" + item.Interactions + "</td>";
                            tabledata += "<td>" + item.Ctr + "</td>";
                            tabledata += "</tr>";

                        }


                        table.innerHTML = tabledata;

                        $("th").css("background-color", "#3399FF");
                        $("tr:even").css("background-color", "#eeeeee");
                        $("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#ffffff");


                    }
                }
                 );


            });

        </script>
```

Here is a JSfiddle of what I want to achieve:
http://jsfiddle.net/3hJYF/4/

So I'm not sure exectly what the problem is.

The arrays that i get are

```
WigetsNameArray:

Dove/ThreeScroll,Dove/FourScroll,Dove/TwoByThree,Dove/OneByThree,OneByFour,OneByFive,Dove/ThreeByTwo,DoveBelliniFacebook/TwoByTwoStandard/UK,Dove-OneBySix,DoveYouTubeEmbed,Dove-OneBySix Phantom2,DoveYouTubeEmbeded,Dove One By Seven Bin 2,Dove three stage Bin 2 FaceBook,Dove One By Seven Bin 2 Facebook,Dove Two By Four UK

impressionsArray:

5568,5597,5670,4966,4612,5146,15403,12907,4008,105,146,40,0,0,0,0

intsArray:

64,76,78,29,46,50,864,198,52,4,2,0,0,0,0,0
```

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data:[impressionsArray]` is **wrong**, just give `data: impressionsArray` and same goes with `data: [intsArray]`, which shall be `data: intsArray` also, the `categories: [WidgetNameArray]` shall be `categories: WidgetNameArray`