# How can I Return a Partial view depending on Controller within current page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

**How do I render a partial view depending on the controller?**

So..I need to render a partial view depending on the values that have been posted:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
                            $("#GetReport").click(function () {
                                $("form[name=StatsForm]").submit();

                            });
                        });
  </script>



<% Html.RenderPartial("InterStats"); %> //this is wrong i need it to render the partial depending on selection and only after the  $("#GetReport").click
```

Controller:

```
 /// <summary>
        /// POST /Stats/Index
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="form"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
        {
            // Deal with the form 
            var manufacturerId = Convert.ToInt32(form["manufacturerId"]);
            var reportId = Convert.ToInt32(form["reportId"]);
            var categoryId = Convert.ToInt32(form["categoryId"]);
            var retailerId = Convert.ToInt32(form["retailerId"]);
            var countryId = Convert.ToInt32(form["countryId"]);
            var regionId = Convert.ToInt32(form["regionId"]);
            var manufacturerWidgetId = (form["ManufacturerWidgetId"]);
            var startDate = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            var endDate = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);    

            var reportName = _reportRepository.GetReport(reportId);


            switch (reportName.Code)
            {
                case "INTER":
                    return RedirectToAction("InterStats",
                                        new
                                        {
                                            manufacturerId = manufacturerId,
                                            countryId = countryId,
                                            startDate = "2013-01-01",
                                            endDate = "2013-01-31"

                                        });
                    break;
                case "CUMLEADS":
                    return RedirectToAction("LeadStats",
                                        new
                                        {
                                            manufacturerId = manufacturerId,
                                            countryId = countryId,
                                            categoryId = categoryId,
                                            startDate = startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                                            endDate = endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                                        });
                    break;
                case "IMP":

                    break;
            }

            return View();


        }




    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// [JsonpFilter]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult InterStats(int manufacturerId, int countryId, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {

        //Get all manufacturerwidgets for manufacturer
        var manufacturerWidget = _manufacturerWidgetsRepository.GetManufacturerWidgetByManufacturerAndCountry(manufacturerId, countryId);
        var interReportJson = new InterReportJson();
        var interRecordList = new List<InterRecord>(); // a list of my anonymous type without the relationships
        interReportJson.InterRecordList = new List<InterRecord>();
        var count = 1;
        foreach (var mw in manufacturerWidget)
        {
            var widgetName = mw.Description;

            //Get the product stats data
            var imps = _productStatsRepository.GetSumImpressionsProductStatsForManufacturerCountryDate(
                mw.Id, countryId, startDate, endDate);


            var clicks = _productStatsRepository.GetSumClicksProductStatsForManufacturerCountryDate(
                mw.Id, countryId, startDate, endDate);

            float ctr = 0;
            if (imps != 0 && clicks != 0)
            {
                ctr = ((clicks / (float)imps) * 100);
            }



            //  Create the data for the report
            var interRecord = new InterRecord
            {
                WidgetName = widgetName,
                Impressions = imps,
                Interactions = clicks,
                Ctr = ctr,
                Count = count
            };




           interReportJson.InterRecordList.Add(interRecord);

            count++;
        }

        interReportJson.Counter = count;




        return PartialView(interReportJson);
    }
```

At the moment without the    <% Html.RenderPartial("InterStats"); %> my partial is opening in a new window and with it its failing as there is no data untill after the form has been submitted. and also It might not be partial "InterStats" it could be partial "LeadsStats"

**Edit**

I was doing the following with AJAX:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

            $("#GetReport").click(function () {


                var manufacturerId = $("#manufacturerId > option:selected").attr("value");
                var countryId = $("#countryId > option:selected").attr("value");
                var startDate = $("#startDate").val();
                var endDate = $("#endDate").val();

                //var manufacturerId = 241;
                //var countryId = 230;
                //                 var startDate = '2013-01-01';
                //                 var endDate = '2013-01-31';

                var theUrl = "/ProductStats/Parameters/" + manufacturerId + "/" + countryId + "/" + startDate + "/" + endDate;

                alert(theUrl);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: theUrl,
                    data: { 'manufacturerId': manufacturerId, 'countryId': countryId, 'startDate': startDate, 'endDate': endDate },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {


                        //see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472947/how-to-format-my-json-data-for-stack-column-chart-in-highcharts


                        var widgetNameArray = [];

                        var impressionsArray = [];

                        var intsArray = [];

                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                            var item1 = data[i];
                            //only display on graph if not 0
                            if (item1.Impressions > 0) {


                                var widgetCategories = item1.WidgetName;

                                //put into an array
                                widgetNameArray.push(widgetCategories);

                                var imps = item1.Impressions;

                                impressionsArray.push(imps);

                                var ints = item1.Interactions;
                                intsArray.push(ints);
                            }
                        }


                        // Create the chart
                        $('#container').highcharts({
                            chart: {
                                type: 'column'
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: 'Inter Chart ' + startDate + ' to ' + endDate
                            },
                            xAxis: {
                                categories: widgetNameArray,
                                labels: {
                                    rotation: -45,
                                    align: 'right',
                                    style: {
                                        fontSize: '13px',
                                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            yAxis: {
                                min: 0,
                                title: {
                                    text: 'Impressions/Interactions'
                                },
                                stackLabels: {
                                    enabled: false,
                                    style: {
                                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            legend: {
                                align: 'right',
                                x: -100,
                                verticalAlign: 'top',
                                y: 20,
                                floating: true,
                                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColorSolid) || 'white',
                                borderColor: '#CCC',
                                borderWidth: 1,
                                shadow: false
                            },
                            tooltip: {
                                formatter: function () {
                                    return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                        this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>';
                                }
                            },
                            plotOptions: {
                                bar: {
                                    dataLabels: {
                                        enabled: true
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            series: [{
                                name: 'Impressions',
                                data: impressionsArray
                            }, {
                                name: 'Interactions',
                                data: intsArray
                            }]
                        });




                        var table = document.getElementById("usertable");
                        var tabledata = "";

                        tabledata += "<tr>";
                        tabledata += "<th>Widget Name</th>";
                        tabledata += "<th>Impressions</th>";
                        tabledata += "<th>Interactions</th>";
                        tabledata += "<th>CTR</th>";
                        tabledata += "</tr>";



                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                            var item = data[i];

                            tabledata += "<tr>";
                            tabledata += "<td>" + item.WidgetName + "</td>";
                            tabledata += "<td>" + item.Impressions + "</td>";
                            tabledata += "<td>" + item.Interactions + "</td>";
                            tabledata += "<td>" + item.Ctr.toFixed(2) + "%</td>";
                            tabledata += "</tr>";

                        }


                        table.innerHTML = tabledata;

                        $("th").css("background-color", "#3399FF");
                        $("tr:even").css("background-color", "#eeeeee");
                        $("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#ffffff");


                    }
                }
                 );


            });

        </script>
```

But this only work for one of the report as the format of the table/chrt varies depending on the report so i nned to seperate how to display them depending on the report id.

I hope it is clear what I need to do please ask if not.

Thanks!

Comment: So...  What's the problem?  You've shown lots of code, but I don't know what you're asking, where you're struggling.  Again, you've shown what you've tried but not where you're stuck.  Maybe consider making your question more clear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks Sam for your input and sorry it wasn t clear what I needed to do.

I actually wanted to choose a partial view depending on which report the user selected from a dropdown list.

So in the view I used a .change so that we knew when the report had been chosen:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[

     $(function () {

         $("#selectReport").hide();
         var manufacturerId;

         $("select#manufacturerId").change(function () {
             manufacturerId = $("#manufacturerId > option:selected").attr("value");
             $("#selectReport").show();

         });


         $("select#reportId").change(function () {
             var reportId = $("#reportId > option:selected").attr("value");

             var theUrl = "/ReportStats/GetReport/" + reportId + "/" + manufacturerId;

             $.ajax({
                 url: theUrl,
                 success: function (data) {
                     $('#ajaxOptionalFields').html(data);
                 },
                 error: function () {
                     alert("an error occured here");
                 }
             });
         });
     });

        //]]>
    </script>
```

In the controller I put a case statement so I knew which report I was on:

//Here we are decinding which partial is going to be seen for which report (so which ajax call will be fired...

```
 switch (report.Code)
            {
                case "INTER":
                    ViewData["InterStats"] = true;
                    break;
                case "CUMLEADS":
                    ViewData["CumLeadsStats"] = true;
                    break;
            }
```

and in the view I put an if statement using this to decide which report partial would be shown:

```
<% if (Convert.ToBoolean(ViewData["InterStats"]))
   { %>
<% Html.RenderPartial("InterReport"); %>
<% }
   else if (Convert.ToBoolean(ViewData["CumLeadsStats"]))
   { %>
<% Html.RenderPartial("CummulativeReport"); %>
<% }  %>
```

I'm not sure if this is a really bad way of doing what i need but it seems to work.

Comment: Looks like you got things figured out, so good job!  As far as alternative things you might have tried - perhaps have separate views for separate reports and the controller chooses a different view.  I didn't downvote, and etiquette on the site is to leave a comment when you do, so its too bad nobody left a comment.  When possible you should mark your answer as the correct one so people don't continue to visit this page to answer your Q.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to call an AJAX method and pass in the necessary data for it to be able to complete the response that you want.  You can do either a GET or a POST.  On a GET put key value pairs on the query string, for a post put key value pairs in the POST body.  You can see jQuery AJAX docs for this.  **Looks like you will have to either do AJAX or a postback for your code to work as it requires user input.**

I'd suggest something like...

```
<div id="reportDiv">
   <!-- dynamic content will be populated here after user makes some selection, etc.. -->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#GetReport").click(function () {
         if (selectionDictatesThatReportBeShown) {
            // Make AJAX call and put response html in the reportDiv
            $('#reportDiv').load('/SomeController/SomeAction?key1=value1&key2=value2');
         }

         // optionally do this?
         $("form[name=StatsForm]").submit();
      });
   });
</script>
```