# highchart dynamically data display using xmlhttp

Tags: javascript, highcharts, xmlhttprequest

i have made changes to my previous script, not sure if its ok to make changes here...
anyway what i am trying to do is
On clicking respective link, i want to load "highchart line graph", so users dont have to leave the page.

my **main.php** body has

```
user2 -- <a href="#" onClick = "showgraph(2)"><img src="go.png"></a><BR>
user3 -- <a href="#" onClick = "showgraph(3)"><img src="go.png"></a>
<script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**head section** contains [**i have made new edits in my javascript, compared to the last one**]

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function showgraph(keyid,serid){
            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "new_graph.php",
            data: "id="+keyid+"&serid="+serid,
            dataType: "json",
                success: function(data){
                drawgraph(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }


    function drawgraph(data){
            alert(data);
            var seriesData = [];
            var xCategories = [];
            var i, cat, series, namedata;
            for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                cat = data[i].ddate;
                series = data[i].dvalue;
                namedata = data[i].dname;
                 //alert(cat);
                 if(xCategories.indexOf(cat) === -1){
                    xCategories[xCategories.length] = cat;
                    seriesData[seriesData.length] = series;
                 }
            }
            //alert(xCategories);
            alert(seriesData);
            //alert(namedata);
    $(function () {
         $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'line',
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 25
            },
            title: {
                text: namedata,
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: Sitename.com',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: xCategories
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Date'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '°C'
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                name: namedata,
                data: seriesData
            }]
        });
    });
    }
</script>
```

**new_graph.php** file returns

I have used php json_encode($data) function.

```
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

returns

```
[{"dvalue":"25","ddate":"2013-07-25","dname":"samsung"},{"dvalue":"26","ddate":"2013-07-26","dname":"samsung"},{"dvalue":"25","ddate":"2013-07-27","dname":"samsung"},{"dvalue":"25","ddate":"2013-07-28","dname":"samsung"},{"dvalue":"24","ddate":"2013-07-29","dname":"samsung"},{"dvalue":"23","ddate":"2013-07-30","dname":"samsung"},{"dvalue":"21","ddate":"2013-07-31","dname":"samsung"},{"dvalue":"23","ddate":"2013-08-01","dname":"samsung"},{"dvalue":"30","ddate":"2013-08-02","dname":"samsung"},{"dvalue":"28","ddate":"2013-08-03","dname":"samsung"},{"dvalue":"25","ddate":"2013-08-04","dname":"samsung"},{"dvalue":"26","ddate":"2013-08-05","dname":"samsung"},{"dvalue":"30","ddate":"2013-08-06","dname":"samsung"},{"dvalue":"25","ddate":"2013-08-07","dname":"samsung"},{"dvalue":"30","ddate":"2013-08-08","dname":"samsung"}]
```

for some reason graph is not showing up with seriesdata, rest of the data getting printed on the graph such as categories and name.

I followed this thread but had no luck
[How to format my json data for stack column chart in HighCharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472947/how-to-format-my-json-data-for-stack-column-chart-in-highcharts)

honestly i'm not good in jquery and highchart. i will appreciate if someone helps me here,
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I see so many potential problems in your code I don't even know where to start without coding it for you.

Here's a hopefully helpful quick list:

1.) When posting to StackOverflow take the time to properly format your code.  If your real code is formatted like that, take the time to space it properly and make it readable.

2.) I would never create a `XMLHttpRequest` object myself these days.  JQuery's AJAX capablities would make your life so much easier (and it would even work in IE).  I would start reading [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

3.) What is `alert(val+date);` supposed to do?  These are two arrays, adding them and alerting is probably not what you intend.

4.) This:

```
for(i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length; i++) {
     var eachval=mySplitResult[i].split("|");
     val.push(eachval[0]);
     date.push(eachval[1]);
}
draw_graph(val,date);
```

is wrong.  Highcharts is going to want numbers for your values (`parseInt` is your friend).

**You probably are going to want to fix your PHP to return proper AJAX instead of manipulating strings.**

5.) Finally check `categories: [date]` and `data: [val]` (these are already arrays, why rewrap in in `[]`)

Comment: hi mark, Thank you for your feedback, I have edited my code a bit, stil having problem, hope you can help me now, thank you in advance

Comment: Hi again, Thank you, its working now, I have taken you advise to use parseInt, so far everything fine now....Thanks again